# Python parameterized SQL adding extra apostrophes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, psycopg2, parameterized

Having an issue with a parameterized psycopg2/flask/postgres query inserting an extra apostrophe and wondering how to stop that. I read every article on here that *seemed* - based on my issue - to answer my question but nope, didn't see any, so here I am! Thanks for any help you can give!

THE ERROR MESSAGE & DEBUG
ERROR

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...R t_name LIKE 'rock' OR t_description LIKE 'rock')) LIMIT 20
```

DEBUG

```
root:getItems: q = SELECT id, t_part_no, id_category, id_user_modified, id_parent, d_modified, t_name, t_description, t_addr_pdf, t_addr_image, t_addr_site FROM tbl_items  WHERE ( b_enabled = %(t_Item_Enabled)s ) AND (%(t_Item_Search)s)) LIMIT %(t_Item_NumShow)s
root:getItems: t_Item_Search = t_part_no LIKE 'rock' OR t_name LIKE 'rock' OR t_description LIKE 'rock'
```

THE RELEVANT PYTHON CODE

```
            t_Item_Search = request.form['box_Search_String']
            t_Item_Where = ""
            t_Item_Where += "t_part_no LIKE '" + t_Item_Search + "'"
            t_Item_Where += " OR t_name LIKE '" + t_Item_Search + "'"
            t_Item_Where += " OR t_description LIKE '" + t_Item_Search + "'"
            t_Item_Search = t_Item_Where

...

    q += " FROM tbl_items "
    q += " WHERE "
    q += "("
    q += " b_enabled = %(t_Item_Enabled)s"
    if t_Item_Search != '':
        q += " ) AND ("
        q += "%(t_Item_Search)s"
        q += ")"
    q += ")"
    if t_Item_OrderBy != '':
        q += " ORDER BY "
        q += "%(t_Item_OrderBy)s "
        q += "%(t_Item_UpDown)s"
    q += " LIMIT %(t_Item_NumShow)s"
    logging.debug("getItems: q = " + q)
    logging.debug("getItems: t_Item_Search = " + t_Item_Search)
    vars = {
        "t_Item_Enabled": (t_Item_Enabled=='True'),
        "t_Item_Search": AsIs(t_Item_Search),
        "t_Item_OrderBy": t_Item_OrderBy,
        "t_Item_UpDown": t_Item_UpDown,
        "t_Item_NumShow": int(t_Item_NumShow)
        }
    db_cursor.execute(q, vars)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AsIs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) to use `t_Item_Search` as SQL representation and not as a string.
You might want to use multi-line strings (using triple quotes), that makes it easier to write longer/more complex sql statements:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
...
cur = conn.cursor()
values = {
    "t_Item_Enabled": True, 
    "t_Item_Search": AsIs(" AND t_part_no LIKE 'rock' OR t_name LIKE 'rock' OR t_description LIKE 'rock'"),
    "t_Item_OrderBy": "", 
    "t_Item_UpDown": "", 
    "t_Item_NumShow": 20
}

sql = """
    SELECT
        foo,
        bar,
        baz
    FROM
        some_table
    WHERE
        (
        b_enabled = %(t_Item_Enabled)s
        )
        %(t_Item_Search)s
    ORDER BY
        baz
    LIMIT
        %(t_Item_NumShow)s
"""
print(cur.mogrify(sql, values).decode('utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
SELECT
    foo,
    bar,
    baz
FROM
    some_table
WHERE
    (
    b_enabled = true
    )
    AND t_part_no LIKE 'rock' OR t_name LIKE 'rock' OR t_description LIKE 'rock'
ORDER BY
    baz
LIMIT
    20
```

Comment: Looks great! I have one question about your output. Noticing no " and " between the b_enabled and the rest of the where clause. Is that a typo or it's totally ok to execute sql that way?

Comment: Forgive my persistence/curiosity. Are you saying no "and" or comma are needed between parts of a WHERE clause? Like "WHERE
    (
    b_enabled = true
    )
    t_part_no ... " vs "WHERE
    (
    b_enabled = true
    ) AND t_part_no... " ?

Comment: Yes, now i see it. You are right I missed an AND :)

Comment: OK then I'm not crazy, hehe. I wasn't sure if it was a Postgres-only mod to SQL, heh.

Comment: Kept upvote for you but removed "solved" checkmark because what you proposed didn't work OR I didn't implement it correctly. Trying to figure out which.

Comment: Edited original code to show current code based on your suggestions. What did I do wrong?

Comment: .. now it's just an SQL syntax error, can you show the output of db_cursor.mogrify(q, vars) ?

Comment: Ha! THAT (using mogrify on the cursor) is what I was trying to figure out! Thank you! Here's the output: SELECT id, t_part_no, id_category, id_user_modified, id_parent, d_modified, t_name, t_description, t_addr_pdf, t_addr_image, t_addr_site FROM tbl_items  WHERE ( b_enabled = true ) AND ( t_part_no LIKE 'rock' OR t_name LIKE 'rock' OR t_description LIKE 'rock')) LIMIT 20

Comment: Aha! Now I see missing "(" at beginning. Let's see if that works...

Comment: It worked! Thank YOU for being so patient with me! Now I need to figure out what to use instead of "%" along with my LIKE statements as a wildcard. Not your problem, though, heh.

Comment: Great, try not to format the SQL statement on your own, like: `t_Item_Where += "t_part_no LIKE '" + t_Item_Search + "'"`, let psycopg2 do this work for you and debug the SQL statement using `mogrify`